# Versioning WCF API based on contract namespaces

Tags: c#, json, api, wcf, versioning

**Hello Everyone.**

**What we want to do :** 
We're working on a versioned API with WCF. Our idea is to change version only by changing namespace of our shared interfaces. (only the N and N-1 versions are going to be visible to the client & implemented server-side).
**We don't want to publish versioned URL**.

*V1 contract :*

```
namespace ServerApp.Interfaces.V1
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "ServerApp.Interfaces.V1")]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/v1/GetVersion")]
        string GetVersion();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/v1/GetData")]
        CompositeType GetData(CompositeType composite);
    }
}
```

*V2 contract :*

Only changes from V1: `namespace ServerApp.Interfaces.V2` & `UriTemplate = "/v2/..."`

*Service.svc :*

```
public class Service : Interfaces.V1.IService, Interfaces.V2.IService
{
    Models.V1.CompositeType Interfaces.V1.IService.GetData(Models.V1.CompositeType composite)
    {
        return null;
    }

    string Interfaces.V1.IService.GetVersion()
    {
        return Business.GetVersion("v1");
    }

    Models.V2.CompositeType Interfaces.V2.IService.GetData(Models.V2.CompositeType composite)
    {
        return null;
    }

    string Interfaces.V2.IService.GetVersion()
    {
        return Business.GetVersion("v2");
    }
}
```

*Service in Web.Config :*

```
<services>
  <service name="ServerApp.Services.Service" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">

    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpExtended"
              contract="ServerApp.Interfaces.V1.IService"
              behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior">
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpExtended"
              contract="ServerApp.Interfaces.V2.IService"
              behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

*Usage in client:*

```
ServerApp.Interfaces.V1;
...
var client = new WebChannelFactory<IService>(new Uri("http://localhost.com:8081/ServerApp/Services/Service.svc")).CreateChannel();   
var v = client.GetVersion(); // ==> returns "v1" cause used interface is V1
```

**This solution is not working.** If the address parameter in `<endpoint ../>` isn't specified, `Multiple Filters Matched` exception is thrown, because of same method in both Contracts, even if UriTemplate is specified.

**Working solution, but not what we want :**
The solution we have for now, is to remove `UriTemplate` from `WebInvoke` in Contracts, add `address` property to endpoints, and specify version in the URL on client side :

```
<endpoint 
     address="v1"
     binding="webHttpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="webHttpExtended"
     contract="ServerApp.Interfaces.V1.IService"
     behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior">

...

[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

...

var client = new WebChannelFactory<IService>(new Uri("http://localhost-ni.cm-cic.fr:8081/ServerApp/Services/Service.svc/v1")).CreateChannel();
```

**Question** Is there any way to make work one service with multiples contracts having the same name but different namespace, without publishing versioned URL ?